# Modbus Error: [Input/Output] Modbus Error: [Invalid Message] No response received, expected at least 8 bytes (0 received)

Tags: python, tcp, modbus

I am trying to connect the Hitachi UX D160W printer using Modbus Ethernet. However i got the error above. Please kindly guide us for correcting the error.

```
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusIOException

# Modbus TCP connection settings
ip_address = '192.168.0.100'
port = 502

# Request message data
transaction_id = 0x0000
protocol_id = 0x0000
data_length = 0x0009
device_address = 0x01
function_code = 0x10
start_address = 0x1042
num_words = 0x0001
num_bytes = 0x02
data = 0x0005

# Create Modbus TCP client
client = ModbusTcpClient(ip_address, port=port)

# Connect to the Modbus TCP server
client.connect()

# Build the request message
request = [
    transaction_id,
    protocol_id,
    data_length,
    device_address,
    function_code,
    start_address,
    num_words,
    num_bytes,
    data
]

try:
    # Send the request message
    response = client.write_registers(start_address, request)

    # Print the response data
    print("Response:", response)

    # Check if an error occurred during Modbus communication
    if isinstance(response, ModbusIOException):
        print("Modbus Error:", response)
    else:
        # Read the response message data
        response_data = response.registers
        print("Response Message Data:")
        print("Transaction Identifier:", hex(response_data[0]))
        print("Protocol Identifier:", hex(response_data[1]))
        print("Data Length:", hex(response_data[2]))
        print("Device Address:", hex(response_data[3]))
        print("Function Code:", hex(response_data[4]))
        print("Start Address:", hex(response_data[5]))
        print("Number of Words to be Written:", hex(response_data[6]))

except Exception as e:
    print("Error:", e)

finally:
    # Close the connection
    client.close()
```

The example of transmission as the below:

1. When you change character size of item 1 of nozzle 1 to “7x10”
   Step 1: write 7 x10 on character size of item 1 of Nozzle 1 by holding register writing. (Function Code: 0x10)

Request Message Data of Holding Register Writing
0000 0000 0009 01 10 1042 0001 02 0005

Response message data of holding register writing
0000 0000 0006 01 10 1042 0001

Content of request message

1. Transaction identifier : 0x0000
2. Protocol Identifier : 0x0000
3. Data Length : 0x0009
4. Device Address :  0x01
5. Functiion Code : 0x10
6. Start Address : 0x1042
7. No of words to be written : 0x0001
8. No of bytes to be written : 0x02
9. Data to be written : 0x0005

Contents of Response Message

1. Transaction identifier : 0x0000
2. Protocol Identifier : 0x0000
3. Data Length : 0x0006
4. Device Address :  0x01
5. Functiion Code : 0x10
6. Start Address : 0x1042
7. No of words to be written : 0x0001

Comment: At a glance, everything seems okay. Have you verified you can access the printer thru your PC/laptop? Have you tried any other programs like Modbus Poll/ComTest Pro to make sure you do have connectivity and you are polling the correct device address?

Comment: [`client.write_registers`](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.2/source/library/client.html#pymodbus.client.mixin.ModbusClientMixin.write_registers) expects an address and then the values to write (it handles the transaction identifier, length, function code etc for you). I believe the command you need is `client.write_registers(start_address, data, slave=1)`. The same applies to the response (it will just give you the registers).

Comment: @NickS., hello sir, thank you very much for guidance, I will try to use the programs according to your recommendation. At the moment, i am able to ping the printer. Is that correct meaning of your connectivity and polling the correct device address? Thank you

Comment: @KennyThien you're welcome, okay; we've established that your computer can see the printer on the network. Now if you use one of the other programs, you can check if you can write or read registers with the device address you are using. Programmatically, I think Brits mentioned an important caveat - the write_registers command doesn't require you to pass in a whole request - building the frame is handled by the client.

Comment: @Brits , thank you very much Brits, i have tried you suggestion, it returned error as Response: Exception Response(144, 16, GatewayNoResponse)
Error: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'registers'

Comment: @NickS. thank you very much sir for your suggestion, i have tried the Modbus Poll , the program return me 0B, Gateway target device failed to respond.

Comment: @KennyThien sounds like you're still having an issue accessing the printer. Which connection option are you using in MBPoll? Modbus over TCP/UDP or Modbus RTU over TCP/UDP? If you haven't tried that yet, I'd try the other option just in case. Are you using Windows or Linux? Can you check if the port is actually open? On Windows in PS, you could try `tnc 192.168.0.100 -port 502` or `nc -zv 192.168.0.100 502` on Linux.

Comment: C:\Users\flash> tnc 192.168.0.100 -port 502                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ComputerName     : 192.168.0.100
RemoteAddress    : 192.168.0.100
RemotePort       : 502
InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress    : 192.168.0.89
TcpTestSucceeded : True

Comment: @NickS. Thank you very much sir for your guidance. I have test using window PS, it return as the above , i believe the port is open. Is my method correct?

Comment: @KennyThien please edit your question when adding info like this (it's much easier to read and means that someone reading it for the first time can see all of the info without needing to dig through the comments). `GatewayNoResponse` is from the device (Modbus exception `0x0B`); this possibly indicates the slave ID is incorrect - are you able to provide a link to the device manual? (without this it's difficult to help).

Comment: @KennyThien yes, that should be fine. As Brits mentioned, a manual would be helpful for us to help you!